# Why do 2 identical function definitions with different names produce two different plots?

Tags: pgfplots

In the code snippet below I would have expected both `r(x)` and `s(x)` to be the same line, but the output is [two radically different lines as shown below](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ym5n0.png).

[image]

If there is a problem using the name `r` as a function name, then I would have expected some sort of error message, but did not find one.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\pgfmathdeclarefunction{r}{1}{\pgfmathparse{(2.0)}}
\pgfmathdeclarefunction{s}{1}{\pgfmathparse{(2.0)}}

\tikzstyle{MyPlotStyle}=[domain=-5:5, samples=50, ultra thick]

\begin{document}
Plot of $r(x)=2$ and $s(x)=2$ using PGF Version \pgfversion.

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}
    \addplot[MyPlotStyle, red ]{r(x)};
    \addplot[MyPlotStyle, blue]{s(x)};
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In `pgfmathparser.code.tex`, `r` is defined as a math operator that applies the `deg` function, to be able to specify angles in radians (`\pgfmathparse{3.14r}\pgfmathresult` yields (almost) 180), so you shouldn't use this name for your own functions. I agree, though, that there should be an error message if you try to define a new function with a name that's already taken by an operator, especially since operators seem to take precedence. You might want to file a bug report / feature request for this.

Comment: I suspected it was something like that but since I saw no error message, I wasn't sure. Where do I file this bug report?

Comment: @Peter: The PGF project uses Sourceforge: http://sourceforge.net/tracker/?group_id=142562