# Defining a macro with if statements

Tags: macros

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Piecewise defined function in tikz or tkz-fct](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/33584/piecewise-defined-function-in-tikz-or-tkz-fct)

I wish to write a macro that gets a number x. If x is smaller than 1, it should return x, otherwise, it returns x^2. I need it for a piece-wise function for TikZ, but I want it as a macro as I will be running it several times. Any easy way to do it?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436). Does [this question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/33584/15925) on piecewise smooth functions in tikz solve your problem?

Comment: Thanks! Indeed I didn't know a simple command such as ifthenelse existed. That works great.

Answer (score 1):

Use pgfmathparse

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{mindmap}

\newcommand*{\mycommand}[1]{%
    \pgfmathparse{
        ifthenelse(#1 < 1,#1,#1*#1)}
    \pgfmathresult
}%
\begin{document}
Less than 1 (x = 0.5)\\
f(x) = \mycommand{0.5}

Equal to 1 (x = 1)\\
f(x) = \mycommand{1}

Greater than 1 (x = 2)\\
f(x) = \mycommand{2}
\end{document}
```

Which yields the following output:

[image: Output]

Calculation on f(n+1) can be achieved with a new function:

```
\newcommand*{\mycommandB}[1]{%
    \pgfmathparse{
        ifthenelse(#1+1 < 1,#1+1,(#1+1)*(#1+1))}
    \pgfmathresult
}%
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, that's pretty much what I did. However, if I want to calculate f(x+1), it doesn't work, i.e. I can't pass the argument "\x+1" to the macro (in the "plot" line). Any way to work around that?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `ifthen` package together with `intcalc`. Then define a macro like this:

```
\newcommand{\test}[1]{\ifthenelse{#1<1}{#1}{\intcalcMul{#1}{#1}}
```