# TikZ - Compute the array being the min of 2 arrays

Tags: tikz-pgf

I define 2 arrays **r** and **p** and draw them.

I would like now to compute the min of **r** and **p** in order to draw it in a similar way. The resulting array would be {0.2, 0.4, 0.8, 0.8, 0.4, 0.0, 0.1, 0.0, 0.1 ,0.5}, but I would like to compute it automatically.

Do you have any idea ?

Here is a MWE regardig the definition and the drawing of **r** and **p** :

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \def\r{{0.2}, {0.4}, {1.0}, {0.8}, {1.0}, {0.0}, {0.3}, {0.5}, {0.1}, {0.5}};
  \def\p{{0.9}, {0.5}, {0.8}, {0.8}, {0.4}, {0.3}, {0.1}, {0.0}, {0.8}, {0.7}};

  \filldraw (0, 0.2) node {$r$}
    \foreach \y [count=\x from 0] in \r { -- (\x, \y) circle[radius=1pt] };
  \filldraw (0, 0.9) node {$r$}
    \foreach \y [count=\x from 0] in \p { -- (\x, \y) circle[radius=1pt] };

\end{tikzpicture}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436). While code snippets are useful in explanations, it is always best to compose a fully compilable [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228) that illustrates the problem including the `\documentclass` and the appropriate packages so that those trying to help don't have to recreate it.

This is especially important for `tikz` as there are numerous libraries. While solving problems can be fun, setting them up is not. Then, those trying to help can simply cut and paste your MWE and get started on solving the problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Basic idea is to iterate through the first list and locate the nth member of the second list and save the minimum into another list.

[image]

### Notes:

- You should avoid single letter variable names, or at least use `\newcommand` which would detect that you are overwriting existing macros.  In this case `\r` is reviously defined. See [Why do 2 identical function definitions with different names produce two different plots?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/19515/why-do-2-identical-function-definitions-with-different-names-produce-two-differe)

### References:

- [How keep a running list of strings and then process them one at a time](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/14393/how-keep-a-running-list-of-strings-and-then-process-them-one-at-a-time)
- [Expansion issue when adding to CSV list from within a \foreach](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/83595/expansion-issue-when-adding-to-csv-list-from-within-a-foreach)

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

%% https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/14393/how-keep-a-running-list-of-strings-and-then-process-them-one-at-a-time
\makeatletter
\newcommand*\@NewList{}%
\newcommand{\ApendToNewList}[1]{%
    %% https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/83595/expansion-issue-when-adding-to-csv-list-from-within-a-foreach
    \begingroup\edef\TempValue{\endgroup%
        \noexpand\g@addto@macro\noexpand\@NewList{\ifx\@NewList\empty\else,\fi#1}}\TempValue%
}

\newcommand*{\ExtractNthValueOfList}[3]{%
    \foreach [count=\i from 1] \x in #3 {%
        \ifnum\i=#2\relax
            \xdef#1{\x}%
            \breakforeach%
         \fi
    }%
}

\newcommand*{\@NthValue}{xx}
\newcommand*{\ExtractMinList}[3]{
    % #1 = variable to contain extract list
    % #2 = first list
    % #3 = second list
    \foreach [count=\j from 1] \y in #2 {%
        \ExtractNthValueOfList{\@NthValue}{\j}{#3}%
        \pgfmathsetmacro{\MinValue}{min(\y,\@NthValue)}%
        \ApendToNewList{\MinValue}%
        \typeout{\j, \y, \@NthValue}% <--- Useful for debugging
    }%
    \edef#1{\@NewList}%
}
\makeatother


\newcommand\RList{{0.2}, {0.4}, {1.0}, {0.8}, {1.0}, {0.0}, {0.3}, {0.5}, {0.1}, {0.5}}
\newcommand\PList{{0.9}, {0.5}, {0.8}, {0.8}, {0.4}, {0.3}, {0.1}, {0.0}, {0.8}, {0.7}}
\newcommand\ExtractedMinList{}% Ensure that we are not overwriting an existing macro

\begin{document}
    \ExtractMinList{\ExtractedMinList}{\RList}{\PList}%
    Extracted List=\ExtractedMinList
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you very much ! Moreover, the ExtractNthValueOfList allows me to extract the first value for the \filldraw loop.